# dodgerCMS - Getting Access Denied. Please make sure the user attached to the access key has access to assets.project.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, content-management-system

I'm trying to setup dodgerCMS http://dodgercms.com/help/installation on my AWS account. I'm getting the following error when trying to login to the manager. I'm sicking help to try to solve the issue:

> manager.project.com/s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com says:
>
> Access Denied. Please make sure the user attached to the access key has access to assets.project.com.

I've found a similar issue (https://github.com/ChrisZieba/dodgercms/issues/3) but the solution didn't resolve it for me.

Here are the steps that I took:

## Setup data.project.com

#### Created data.project.com S3 bucket:

```
aws  s3api create-bucket --bucket data.project.com --region us-west-1 --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=us-west-1
```

#### Create data-cors.json:

```
{
  "CORSRules": [
   {
      "AllowedOrigins": ["*"],
      "AllowedHeaders": ["*"],
      "AllowedMethods": ["HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE"],
      "ExposeHeaders": ["ETag", "x-amz-meta-title", "x-amz-meta-label"]
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Edited data.project.com CORS:

```
aws  s3api put-bucket-cors --bucket data.project.com --cors-configuration file://~/data-cors.json
```

## Setup assets.project.com

#### Created assets.project.com S3 bucket:

```
aws  s3api create-bucket --bucket assets.project.com --region us-west-1 --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=us-west-1
```

#### Create assets-policy.json:

```
{
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": "*",
         "Action": "s3:GetObject",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::assets.project.com/*"
      }
   ]
}
```

#### Edited assets.project.com policy

```
aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket assets.project.com --policy file://~/assets-policy.json
```

#### Create assets-cors.json:

```
{
  "CORSRules": [
    {
      "AllowedOrigins": ["*"],
      "AllowedHeaders": ["*"],
      "AllowedMethods": ["HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE"],
      "ExposeHeaders": ["ETag"]
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Edited assets.project.com CORS:

```
aws  s3api put-bucket-cors --bucket assets.project.com --cors-configuration file://~/assets-cors.json
```

## Setup project.com

#### Created project.com S3 bucket:

```
aws  s3api create-bucket --bucket project.com --region us-west-1 --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=us-west-1
```

#### Configure bucket as a website

```
aws s3 website s3://project.com/ --index-document index.html --error-document error.html
```

#### Create web-policy.json:

```
{
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": "*",
         "Action": "s3:GetObject",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::datacoral.io/*"
      }
   ]
}
```

#### Edited project.com policy

```
aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket project.com --policy file://~/web-policy.json
```

#### Create web-cors.json:

```
{
  "CORSRules": [
    {
      "AllowedOrigins": ["*"],
      "AllowedHeaders": ["*"],
      "AllowedMethods": ["HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE"],
      "ExposeHeaders": ["ETag", "x-amz-meta-title", "x-amz-meta-label"]
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Edited project.com CORS:

```
aws  s3api put-bucket-cors --bucket project.com --cors-configuration file://~/web-cors.json
```

## Setup manager.project.com

#### Created manager.project.com S3 bucket:

```
aws  s3api create-bucket --bucket manager.project.com --region us-west-1 --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=us-west-1
```

#### Configure bucket as a website

```
aws s3 website s3://manager.project.com/ --index-document index.html --error-document error.html
```

#### Uploaded files to manager.project.com

```
aws --profile dccustomer s3 sync ~/dodgercms s3://manager.project.com/ --acl public-read
```

## Created a user with the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1427944232000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetBucketWebsite",
                "s3:PutBucketWebsite",
                "s3:DeleteBucketWebsite",
                "s3:GetBucketLogging",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::data.project.com",
                "arn:aws:s3:::data.project.com/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::assets.project.com",
                "arn:aws:s3:::assets.project.com/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::project.com",
                "arn:aws:s3:::project.com/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:GetFederationToken",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've asked the same question at the dodgercms repo on github: https://github.com/ChrisZieba/dodgercms/issues/10

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I did but it's been a while. I'll look into it and update it here.